# Kendo UI error on ASP.NET MVC 4 page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 page with a Kendo Menu.
All works fine until I set debug="false" in web.config.
This is the Webpage Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'kendoMenu'.
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Can you share your code, the full stack trace, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the kendo files you have are ONLY .min files, probably not regular uncompressed kendo file.  If you don't want to set debug=false, try

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

In your BundleConfig.cs

Answer (score 1):

Official answer from KendoUI team: http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/general-discussions/vs2012-rtm-mvc4-kendo-bundle-not-rendering.aspx:

> In ASP.NET MVC 4 RC the bundles included minified JavaScript and CSS files in debug mode (). In ASP.NET MVC 4 this is no longer the case - minified files are ignored in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in the Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization package (that deals with bundling and minification) in that the optimizer fails to include minified files in debug mode. With the Kendo code you generally *only* have minified files - so BOOM.
You could follow the workaround in the above link, or as an alternative if you have Kendo license if you look in the install folder you'll find the non minified js and css files. Include these in your project and you should be fine.
MS have acknowledged this bug and and it should be fixed in the next release of the optimizer.